# Unit testing methods with side effect

Tags: unit-testing

As far as I know "unit test should not be testing internal implementation details in order to not complicate the refactoring of the method". So, how can I test this method?

```
deleteOrder = (order) ->
    backendService('deleteOrder', order.id)
    cacheOfOrders.delete(order)
```

From my unit testing environment (jasmine) I can call deleteOrder and mock the backend call, but I can't access to the cacheOfOrders. I wanted to check that the cacheOfOrders.length was reduced in one. Maybe I'm doing it wrong and I should not test internal details, but what if I have one method like the previous one but without a backend call?

Comment: Can you create a `cachOfOrders` object as a separate test that you can run?

Comment: cacheOfOrders is private to the service in question. I cannot access or make a reference to it.

Comment: What I mean is, what is cacheOfOrders an instance of? Can you test a new instance of that class instead of trying to test it via the internal workings of what actually implements it? If it is a custom class that a developer created you should test it. If it is a standard class provided by the framework, you should not need to bother with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flexible solution would to make your cache an injectable argument to whatever it is you're doing here, so you could pass a mock cache object that you can then test on.

Barring that, do you have a method which you can use to look up an order from the cache? You could assert that the cache doesn't return a valid entry after your `deleteOrder` call. If your lookup avoids a backendService call if the item is present in the cache, then you could test to ensure that after a delete, a lookup call does in fact hit the backendService (which would imply that the cache is not populated). That is, test the effects of the cache operating properly, rather than testing the cache itself.

Comment: I didn't write the method, I'm part of a "unit testing team" (ugh). The cache is not accesible and it hasn't any public interface... I'm starting to think that the cache is a very internal detail.

Answer (score 1):

First aspect, should the proper handling of the cache be tested?  Yes, for various reasons.  For one thing, the cache is there for a reason (maybe performance, maybe ability to do things if connections break, ...).  Moreover, the cache consumes memory or other types of resources.  Consequently, if the cache is not operated correctly the software may not meet the intended goals, and it may even fail at other places because of resource leaks.

Second aspect, how should the proper use of the cache be tested?  The cache does (probably) not alter the functional behaviour of the code.  It should alter, probably, performance, so it may be possible to check at least that aspect - although it is hard to evaluate if you don't have comparison data.  And, for the specific function you have given as example it does not help, because it is cache cleanup code, where the performance impact is not apparent.

Therefore, the proper approach is to make the cache accessible or injectable in some way.  In other words, the design would have to be modified in some way to improve testability.  The keywords are controllability (if you make the cache injectable you are using inversion of control) and/or observability (if alternatively you make the cache accessible for the tests).  The code as you describe it has neither.

Which brings us to the third aspect (which you have not explicitly asked about), whether the unit-testing process that your organisation practices is proper.  Namely (as you mention in one comment) that there is a dedicated unit-testing team, which has to test the code as is, without possibility to make changes for the sake of testability.

Probably I don't have to tell *you*, as you are the one suffering from it, but I couldn't resist: Such an approach for unit-testing is certainly highly disadvantageous.

- There is for one thing the point you observe: Code that comes from developers who do not write (at least some of) the tests is not well testable.  This means that the effort for testing is higher and that, despite the higher effort for testing, it can still not be done to the desired extent.
- Even the tests that can be performed by the test team are of lower value, because typically they come late (development moves on while the testers still try to test the delivered version), and most likely once an update of the software is handed over to the testers it will cost them again a lot of time to get the tests compile again with the new software version.  And, in such a scenario it is often even unclear for the testers if an observed behaviour is intended or not...
- Finally, the developers themselves typically do not benefit from this approach, since they can not even use the test suite directly to see if their changes have lead to a regression.

Conclusion: The real problem is the organisational setup and the testing process - unfortunately probably also the most difficult things to change.